# .htaccess redirect: www not working

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect a domain alias to a specific page on my site. I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^afdekfolie.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.technosales.be/wordpress/afdekfolie/ [R=301,L]
```

This works when entering afdekfolie.be as the alias, but not when entering www.afdekfolie.be

How do I make this work?

Thanks,
Stefaan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are asking this rule to work for the host starting with afdekfolie...

Try this one

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?afdekfolie\.be$ [NC]
```

Or you can break it into two rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^afdekfolie\.be$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.afdekfolie\.be$ [NC]
```

ps: how is this related to the `php` tag?

Comment: You're right about the php tag, it was suggested. Removed it.